# How to remove spaces in Android string resource caused by XML newline?

Tags: android

I have a very long string in my Android project, so I split it across multiple lines:

```
<string name="my_str">
    AAAAAAAAAAA
    BBBBBBBBBBB
</string>
```

When I use this string, I get `AAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBB`. Is there a way to get rid of the space in the middle? (I want `AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB`)

Obviously I could put the entire string on one line, but that's not very maintainable.

Edit: The string (AAA...BBB) can contain spaces; I only want to remove the spaces created by the newline in the XML.

Comment: what if you break with shift+enter?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all whitespaces and non-visible characters (e.g. tab, newline,..):

```
mystring.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

or to remove new-lines

```
mystring.replaceAll("\n","");
```

Answer (score 1):

So remove all white spaces from beginning and from end:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("^\\s+","").replaceAll("\\s+$","");
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): `^` is for beginning, `$` for end. `\s` means any white space like tabs, spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = myString.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I only want to remove the extra spaces created by the newline in the XML.

Comment: Yes, probably I understood your question wrongly. I paid attention to this part: "I get AAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBB. Is there a way to get rid of the space in the middle? (I want AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB )"  so I am sorry for inappropriate answer. To remove newline symbol you can use "\n" instead of " ".

Answer (score 0):

**Remove white space in string array**
It's very simple to remove from white space in string array.
for example:-
String rahul = 12, 13, 14, 15, 16

Solution :

```
rahul.trim().replaceAll("\\s","");
```

output is : 12,13,14,15,16